# Is there a way to get the elment from the aria-controls attribute using React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, react-testing-library, wai-aria

Suppose a React component returns the following JSX, which represents a simple [Collapsible](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp):

```html
<>
  <button
    onClick={onClickHandler}
    aria-controls="collapsible"
    aria-expanded={expanded}
    aria-label="collapsible"
  />

  <div
     id="collapsible"
     aria-hidden={!expanded}
  />
  </div>
</>
```

According to [Harvard: Technique: Expandable sections](https://accessibility.huit.harvard.edu/technique-expandable-sections) and [Inclusive Components: Collapsible Sections](https://inclusive-components.design/collapsible-sections/)
 the provided example should be accessible for screen readers; a real user can easily interact with the component.

I'm unable to query for the Collapsile content using an accessible role with the [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/). However, the content is accessible, as the button is accessible and it controls the div, perceived from the `aria-controls`-attribute.

Is there maybe a way to get the elment from the aria-controls attribute using React Testing Library, which I haven't come across? Something like `screen.getByRole('button').aria-controls`?

Comment: could you use aria-label ? https://testing-playground.com/gist/76d1d770d944189cab4213c5f006d99c/47c38004d0cab41b750192d1a46c735e9c47e576

Comment: @KcH I don't think that will work on the div with the content.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `hidden={!expanded}` and not `aria-hidden`?

Comment: `<div>` has role generic, which you could use to find it, but it doesn’t make sense. I believe that the idea of the testing library is to go find elements by properties that the test provides to the Component. In this case, that would be the [text contents](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytext) of the `<div>`. Like `getByText(/collapsible content/i)`.